# Overriding MUI Stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I need to change a Mui Stepper ( which the code works perfetly )
but what I need is a bit different ,
Instead of having this : [image: the render of the code]

I want to get the text under the icon and instead of having a line between tow steps I prefer to have a '<'

Here is the code :

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Stepper from '@mui/material/Stepper';
import Step from '@mui/material/Step';
import StepButton from '@mui/material/StepButton';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const steps = ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];

export default function HorizontalNonLinearStepper() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState<{
    [k: number]: boolean;
  }>({});

  const totalSteps = () => {
    return steps.length;
  };

  const completedSteps = () => {
    return Object.keys(completed).length;
  };

  const isLastStep = () => {
    return activeStep === totalSteps() - 1;
  };

  const allStepsCompleted = () => {
    return completedSteps() === totalSteps();
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    const newActiveStep =
      isLastStep() && !allStepsCompleted()
        ? // It's the last step, but not all steps have been completed,
          // find the first step that has been completed
          steps.findIndex((step, i) => !(i in completed))
        : activeStep + 1;
    setActiveStep(newActiveStep);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleStep = (step: number) => () => {
    setActiveStep(step);
  };

  const handleComplete = () => {
    const newCompleted = completed;
    newCompleted[activeStep] = true;
    setCompleted(newCompleted);
    handleNext();
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
    setCompleted({});
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Stepper nonLinear activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label} completed={completed[index]}>
            <StepButton color="inherit" onClick={handleStep(index)}>
              {label}
            </StepButton>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      <div>
        {allStepsCompleted() ? (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>
              All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
              <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
              <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
            </Box>
          </React.Fragment>
        ) : (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>Step {activeStep + 1}</Typography>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
              <Button
                color="inherit"
                disabled={activeStep === 0}
                onClick={handleBack}
                sx={{ mr: 1 }}
              >
                Back
              </Button>
              <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
              <Button onClick={handleNext} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                Next
              </Button>
              {activeStep !== steps.length &&
                (completed[activeStep] ? (
                  <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                    Step {activeStep + 1} already completed
                  </Typography>
                ) : (
                  <Button onClick={handleComplete}>
                    {completedSteps() === totalSteps() - 1
                      ? 'Finish'
                      : 'Complete Step'}
                  </Button>
                ))}
            </Box>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to override the MUI Stepper styles ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox?

Comment: How can I do that please ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/e43nyv?file=/demo.tsx ??

Comment: I'm working on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so basically it was 2 steps. The first one was to make the labels appear below the icons which was relatively easy.

I had to add `alternativeLabel` as a prop to the `<Stepper />`.

The next step was to remove the lines and replace them with `<` which wasn't straightforward. I did that by styling the `.MuiStepConnector` class, replacing its content and removing the border.

```
      <Stepper
        nonLinear
        alternativeLabel
        activeStep={activeStep}
        sx={{
          ".MuiStepConnector-root": {
            top: 0
          },
          ".MuiStepConnector-root span": {
            borderColor: "transparent"
          },
          ".MuiStepConnector-root span::before": {
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            content: '"<"'
          }
        }}
      >
```

This is the result:

[image][image: Edit HorizontalNonLinearStepper demo — Material UI (forked)]

Comment: Ohh man I am very grateful , it is very kind of you :-)